# Cloudflare blocking wordpress load-scripts.php long url

Tags: wordpress, security, cloudflare, owasp

on one of our Wordpress application we have Cloudflare, and from a month ago we noticed a problem, that our javascripts are not loading. The url is:
    `https://somedomain.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,jquery-query,admin-comments,suggest,jquer&load%5B%5D=y-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,tags-suggest,tags-box,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,wp-plupload,mediael&load%5B%5D=ement,wp-mediaelement,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,image-edit,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,jquery-ui-tabs,jqu&load%5B%5D=ery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,media-upload,wp-pointer,editor,wplink,wp-embed&ver=4.8.9`

When we enter this url in our browser it shows Cloudflare page and captcha to enter "One more step. Please complete the security check to access.."
So probably the url is too long, and Cloudflare Owasp security see problems in that.

This problem comes probably from Wordpress load-scripts.php file (code below), which join files in one, and we have a lot of plugins.

What can we do with that?

1. We could try to rewrite that code, and split this file to several, but we would like to not modify Wordpress file :/
2. Maybe there is any plugin which does this?

```
function _print_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts, $compress_scripts;
    $zip = $compress_scripts ? 1 : 0;
    if ( $zip && defined('ENFORCE_GZIP') && ENFORCE_GZIP )
        $zip = 'gzip';
    if ( $concat = trim( $wp_scripts->concat, ', ' ) ) {
        if ( !empty($wp_scripts->print_code) ) {
            echo "\n<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
            echo "/* <![CDATA[ */\n"; // not needed in HTML 5
            echo $wp_scripts->print_code;
            echo "/* ]]> */\n";
            echo "</script>\n";
        }
        $concat = str_split( $concat, 128 );
        $concat = 'load%5B%5D=' . implode( '&load%5B%5D=', $concat );
        $src = $wp_scripts->base_url . "/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c={$zip}&" . $concat . '&ver=' . $wp_scripts->default_version;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . esc_attr($src) . "'></script>\n";
    }
    if ( !empty($wp_scripts->print_html) )
        echo $wp_scripts->print_html;
}
```

Comment: My wordpress foo is not too strong, but have you tried setting `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` in your wp-config.php? This might be a quick solution to have your site up and running. This will slightly slow down the initial load of the wp-admin area.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Auto Minify

- Log into the dashboard.
- Select your account and website.
- Go to Speed > Optimization.
- Select the file types to minify.

check your wordpress [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eEIu.png).

Try to use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/#:%7E:text=wp_enqueue_scripts%20is%20the%20proper%20hook%20to%20use%20when,is%20used%20for%20enqueuing%20both%20scripts%20and%20styles.)

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_script');

function load_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jsfile', plugins_url( '/js/jsfile.js', __FILE__ ));
}
```

where `load_script` is the handler from [`wp_register_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/). Please check [maximum browsers url length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) and [load-script.php not loading](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256801/wordpress-load-scripts-php-not-loading), hope this help.